# Нужно сделать изображение по высоте 100%

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу сделать, чтоб изображение было по высоте родительского блока.

```css
.mini-news__item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<li class="mini-news__item">
  <a href="#" class="mini-news__link">
    <article class="mini-news__post">
      <div class="mini-news__img">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b9/cb/51/b9cb51c6c94d167e334ef2a893609082--google-images.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3 class="mini-news__title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </article>
  </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно дать контейнеру относительное позиционировния, а картинке - абсолютное, тогда они станут "ближайшими родственниками" и можно легко их позиционировать относительно друг друга.

```css
.mini-news__item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.mini-news__img>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<li class="mini-news__item">
  <a href="#" class="mini-news__link">
    <article class="mini-news__post">
      <div class="mini-news__img">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b9/cb/51/b9cb51c6c94d167e334ef2a893609082--google-images.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3 class="mini-news__title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </article>
  </a>
</li>
```

Можно стандартизировать все блоки внутри контейнера, чтобы каждый из них был блокоподобным и имел 100% высоту относительно своего родителя.

```css
.mini-news__item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.mini-news__item * {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<li class="mini-news__item">
  <a href="#" class="mini-news__link">
    <article class="mini-news__post">
      <div class="mini-news__img">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b9/cb/51/b9cb51c6c94d167e334ef2a893609082--google-images.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3 class="mini-news__title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </article>
  </a>
</li>
```

Можно провести точечные изменения для каждого элемента, чтобы они все в итоге были по высоте своего родителя.

```css
.mini-news__item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
}

.mini-news__item>.mini-news__link {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}

.mini-news__item>.mini-news__link>.mini-news__post {
  height: 100%;
}

.mini-news__item>.mini-news__link>.mini-news__post>.mini-news__img {
  height: 100%;
}

.mini-news__item>.mini-news__link>.mini-news__post>.mini-news__img>img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<li class="mini-news__item">
  <a href="#" class="mini-news__link">
    <article class="mini-news__post">
      <div class="mini-news__img">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/236x/b9/cb/51/b9cb51c6c94d167e334ef2a893609082--google-images.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3 class="mini-news__title">Lorem ipsum</h3>
    </article>
  </a>
</li>
```

Выбирайте под свою задачу.